# MySQL date string to date format in new columns

Tags: mysql, string, date

There is a column in a table which contains date like this:

`Thursday, February 28, 2019 (All day) to Friday, March 15, 2019 (All day)`

OR

`Thursday, February 28, 2019 (All day)`

I want to split these dates in 2 new fields with date format (I don't care for time part of the string which can occur instead of "(All day)").

So : `Date` is the existing field and `From-To` are the new ones

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
|                                   Date                                    |    From    |     To     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| Thursday, February 28, 2019 (All day) to Friday, March 15, 2019 (All day) | 2019-02-28 | 2019-03-15 |
| Thursday, February 28, 2019 (All day)                                     | 2019-02-28 | NULL       |
| Monday, February 11, 2019 - 14:00 to Friday, February 15, 2019 - 14:00    | 2019-02-11 | 2019-02-15 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Can anything other than "all day" appear next to a date string, and, if so, what other values are possible?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it can be time but I don't care for this part, I only care for the date part. Thx for asking so I updated my post for clarification

Comment: Honestly your ask is stretching the limits of what MySQL was really intended to be doing.  Is there any chance that you could reimport your date information as two columns with strings containing date-only information?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well I import them from a csv file. I dont know if it is easier to update somehow the csv file and then import it to my db

Comment: quick thought: I would look for the string `to` and split the string. Then the same looking for `-` or `(All day)`. And what you have left is the date to be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that this is the exact format of the rows and no surprises may come, you can do it with string functions like [`substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [`trim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) and finally [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
select  
  date Date,
  str_to_date(
    trim(substring_index(date, '(All day)', 1)),
    '%W, %M %d, %Y'
  ) `From`, 
  case when date like '% to %' then                    
    str_to_date(
      trim(replace(replace(substring_index(date, '(All day)', -2), '(All day)', ''), 'to', '')),
    '%W, %M %d, %Y'
  ) else null end `To`                       
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kgjpeH4tjEUo2XBYzaajbT/1).
Results:

```
| Date                                                                      | From       | To         |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| Thursday, February 28, 2019 (All day) to Friday, March 15, 2019 (All day) | 2019-02-28 | 2019-03-15 |
| Thursday, February 28, 2019 (All day)                                     | 2019-02-28 |            |
```

Edit
To cover the case of time existing in the rows:

```
select
  date,
  str_to_date(
    trim(substring_index(d, '-', 1)),
    '%W, %M %d, %Y'
  ) `From`,
  case when date like '% to %' then
    str_to_date(     
      trim(substring_index(substring_index(d, ' to ', -1), '-', 1)),
      '%W, %M %d, %Y'
    )                     
    else null
  end `To`  
from (
  select 
    date,
    replace(date, '(All day)', '-') d
  from tablename  
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kgjpeH4tjEUo2XBYzaajbT/3).

Comment: Well if you see my updated post surprises may come... as instead of (All day) time may occur.... Please check my updated post, thank you for helping me though

Answer (score 1):

The `STR_TO_DATE()` function would most likely be at least part of the solution here.  Assuming each of the from and to columns contained only a date string, we could try:

```
SELECT
    STR_TO_DATE('Thursday, February 28, 2019', '%W, %M %d, %Y') AS date_out
FROM dual;
```

But note that the best thing to do here is to completely ditch those text dates.  So really you should be doing something like:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET from_date = STR_TO_DATE(from_date_str, '%W, %M %d, %Y');
```

Then, drop the original text date columns.

Comment: Keep in mind that using `STR_TO_DATE(.., , '%W, %M %d, %Y')`  on `Thursday, February 28, 2019 (All day) to Friday, March 15, 2019 (All day)` can give truncation errors/warnings, you might want to include `LEFT()/SUBSTRING()` here as that is more correct for the data example..

Comment: Well coffee time i indeed missed the detail... *"Assuming each of the from and to columns contained only a date string, we could try"*

Comment: @RaymondNijland LOL...it's beer time in Singapore `^ ^`

Comment: We Dutch poeple live in the past timezone wise we are 9 hours behide Singapore always fun those timezones..